# How to prove that a function f(x) is O(g(x)), using the definition (finding C and k)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, asymptotics

We say that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if
$$(∃C ∈ \mathbb(R)❘)(∃k ∈ \mathbb(R)❘)(∀x ∈ \mathbb(R)❘)$$
$$(x ≥ k → |f(x)| ≤ C · |g(x)|)$$
In English: We can find $C$ and $k$ so that, once we
get past the “small values” of $x$, $f(x)$ is at most a
constant times $g(x)$.
Usually, $f(x)$ will be complicated, and $g(x)$ will be
simple.

These are all the notes we've been given in class about proofs using big-O notation and our professor has basically parroted the same thing back to us when it's been taught. Most everything I can find is too complicated or involved to even apply to what we're using it for, but apparently it's a very important concept that I'm failing to grasp. Is there any way someone knows to explain this in a simple fashion that makes sense to me? That sounds like a lot to ask, but I'm pretty desperate. I've never gotten a proof correct in this class and it drives me insane. So I need to know how to prove something using the definition of Big-O notation by finding $C $ and $k$.

Comment: The best way is to give us an example.

Comment: Pick one from [here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci220s1t/lectures/lecturenotes/GG-lectures/BigOhexamples.pdf).

Comment: Okay, *what* don't you understand about it?

Comment: Everything after "Let us check this condition"

Comment: They are trying to find a $c$ so that the inequality holds.